# BIDS - Solution Explorer vs Report Data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence, bids

In Business Intelligence Development Studio, what exactly is the difference between the objects (i.e., dataset, data sources, etc) in the Solution Explorer and the Report Data tab? Both have different datasets, but they impact the final report differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer you have **Shared Data Sources** and **Shared Datasets**.

[image]

These are self-contained items that can be deployed to the Report Server.

In the Report Data tab you have **Data Sources** and **Datasets**.

[image]

These are items that are internal to and relevant to the selected report only.

Both Shared Data Sources/Datasets and report Data Sources/Datasets perform the same function, i.e. defining a connection to a data source and extracting specific data from a defined data source respectively.

In an individual report, when you define a Data Source or Dataset (i.e. in the Report Data tab) you have two options - you can store all the details embedded in the report or you can reference a Shared Data Source/Dataset.

[image]

[image]

The advantage of using Shared items is that you can define the details and use the item in multiple reports, hence helping with maintenance and manageability. For example, from Books Online:

> Shared data sources are useful when you have data sources that you use
>   often. It is recommended that you use shared data sources as much as
>   possible. They make reports and report access easier to manage, and
>   help to keep reports and the data sources they access more secure.

So, Shared items in the Solution define connections that can be used by multiple reports and are also deployed to the report server, while the items in the Report Data tab define those connections for the selected report; these can either reference a Shared item or have all the data embedded in the report itself.

More information:

[Embedded and Shared Data Connections or Data Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[Embedded and Shared Datasets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633675%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)